# Can I use reactive extensions to queue calls to a windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have a window service that is calling a non-thread safe api (ghostscript) to convert pdf's to images so I need to ensure the method call is called one at a time but queue all the calls which can be coming from various app instances.

app -> windows service -> ghostscript

Comment: The reactive extensions seem a little heavy for a task that would be better suited for just a simple lock.

Comment: A semaphore would block execution but I need to queue all the calls to the service and make sure they are done. I thought it should be simpler to queue the calls instead of forcing the apps to fight over the service.

Comment: +1.  I have a similar situation which I'm handling using a thread safe queue serviced by a number of different threads.  Been wondering if I should ditch my implementation (exactly *how well* can one test multithreaded code??) for Rx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var eventLoop = new EventLoopScheduler();

IObservable<Unit> QueueAnItem(string input) 
{
    return Observable.Start(() => CallGhostScriptAndWaitForItToFinish(input), eventLoop);
}

QueueAnItem("Foo").Subscribe(
    x => Console.WriteLine("It Finished!"), 
    ex => Console.WriteLine("Something Bad Happened: {0}", ex.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Rx is a bit of overkill for the job. Consider [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585582) if you have complex queuing/wait/batching needs.

If your requirements are simple, you can go for the simple `Task.Start(...)`, `Task.ContinueWith(...)` to create a thread-safe processing queue of sorts.

It could be as simple as:

```
public class TaskQueue
{
    protected Task Pending;
    public bool Ready { get { return Pending == null || Pending.IsCompleted || Pending.IsCanceled || Pending.IsFaulted; } }

    public Task Enqueue(Action work)
    {
        lock (this)
            return Pending = Ready ? Task.Factory.StartNew(work) : Pending.ContinueWith(_ => work());
    }
}
```

The easiest way to test this is to use TPL, so:

```
var tasks = new TaskQueue();
Func<int, Action> queue = i => () => tasks.Enqueue(
() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, i); });

Parallel.Invoke
(
    queue(1),
    queue(2),
    queue(3),
    queue(4)
);
```

Results:

```
3/10/2012 5:59:02 PM: 1
3/10/2012 5:59:03 PM: 2
3/10/2012 5:59:04 PM: 3
3/10/2012 5:59:05 PM: 4
```

Comment: Downvoters care to explain? OP's question is "Can I use reactive extensions", as opposed to "how do I do it using Rx"

Comment: Your reasonable code sample now earns you my downvote revocation and replacement with an upvote